# How to get a reasonable file size when converting from MP4 to WMV?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, wmv

I converted an MP4 1080 movie to WMV. The result is a huge 9 GB file. How can I convert it (using FFmpeg) so that the file is decent quality but not huge? Or, how can I split a 9 GB WMV file to two smaller files that can fit on DVD discs?

Comment: For the purpose of playing it back on an HD TV? Not much point. Most DVD players can't handle HD. If you burned that to a DVD in such a way that the DVD player could read it, it would be automatically downsampled to a (high-DVD-quality) SD format for standard DVD (4.3GB).

Comment: Yep. Xyon is right. It is a waste of resources. Unless you plan to write this to a blue-ray disk, you won't be able to use 1080p. HD dvds really are only 720p.

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be a WMV file in the first place? There's usually less playback support for WMV than for MP4 files, anywhere. Also, while converting you'll lose quality, which means that if you tried to make your result file considerably smaller, you'd probably find it pretty bad in terms of visual quality.

Answer (score 1):

From Digiarty WinXDVD: [Compress Video in FFmpeg](https://www.winxdvd.com/resize-video/compress-video-with-ffmpeg.htm)

**Part 1.** [How to Reduce Video Size with FFmpeg (Command-Line)](https://www.winxdvd.com/resize-video/compress-video-with-ffmpeg.htm#part1) *(excerpt below)*

> Command-line - Compress and Convert MP4 to WMV
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 1000k -vcodec wmv2 -acodec \
> wmav2 -crf 19 -filter:v fps=fps=24 output.wmv
> ```
>
> Command-line - Compress and Convert MP4 to Webm for YouTube, Ins, Facebook
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0.33M -c:a \
> libopus -b:a 96k -filter:v scale="960x540" target.webm
> ```
>
> Command-line - Compress and Convert H.264 to H.265 for Higher Compression
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4
> ```
>
> Command-line -Set CRF in FFmpeg to Reduce Video File Size
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 output.mp4
> ```
>
> Command-line - Reduce video frame size to make 4K/1080P FHD video smaller
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=1280:720 output.avi
> ```
>
> Command-line - resize video in FFmpeg to reduce video size
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=852×480 output.avi
> ```
>
> You can resize your video to a specific size 480p, 720p, 1080p, etc. in FFmpeg.
>
> If you need to resize video in FFmpeg but keep the original aspect ratio, specify only one component, width or height, and set the other component to -1, for example,
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale=852:-1 output_852.png
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User @fhanik Great example of when it makes sense to answer an old question.  10 Years old with no answers.  I suggested some formatting edits. +10

Comment: Thanks for the help @BlindSpots